# keras: extractor one layer as a model

Tags: keras

There are several good answers for getting the output of a intermediate layer in keras model. But I want to extract one layer in a keras model, and use the layer's input as the new model's input, output as the new model's output. And I have tried:

```
extractor = Model(model.get_layer('dw_conv5').input, model.get_layer('dw_conv5').output)
```

But there is an error:

> Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs:   Tensor("leaky_re_lu_4/LeakyRelu/Maximum:0", shape=(?, 3, 3, 256), dtype=float32). Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `LeakyReLU`.

Comment: TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputs = Input(a_compatible_shape)
outputs = model.get_layer('dw_conv5')(inputs)

model = Model(inputs,outputs)
```